# Open source notes app for iOS with website

Tags: open-source, web-apps, ios, note-taking

I am looking for an open source note app for iOS which also provides a website so I can access my notes from every device with a working internet connection (like Google Keep).

Features would be:

- Create, update, delete and view
- Accessible via iOS app and website
- Sync

This website can either be hosted by the developer or can be downloaded and installed on my private server (which would be better).